# Keras: How to shape 2-D data (time, feature vector) into 3D

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have a training data with length 8474, and each element being a 5-dimensional feature vector at a discrete time. I am trying to run an LSTM in Keras:

```
 x_training, x_testing = x_data[:8475], x_data[8475:]
 y_training, y_testing = y_data[:8475], y_data[8475:]

 primary = Sequential()
 primary.add(LSTM(4,input_shape=(5,)))
 primary.add(LSTM(4, activation='sigmoid'))
 primary.add(Dense(1))

 primary.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', 
                 loss='binary_crossentropy', 
                 metrics=['accuracy'])

 primary.fit(x_training, y_training, batch_size=20, epochs=10, shuffle=False)
 score, accuracy = primary.evaluate(x_testing, y_testing, batch_size=20, verbose=0)
```

And:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_4: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

I know that I have to convert this 8475 X 5 data into 3D data with the setup (nb_samples, nb_included_previous_days, features), but I do not understand: What is the difference between the timestep and length of training data? Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference between the timestep and length of training data? Am I missing something else?

Timestep is number of RNN/LSTM cells in model and that depends on your sequence length.

First to use LSTM you need to convert your training data in 3D format. Suppose you are working on some time series problem and for prediction of each instant in training data, you considers previous/adjacent 10 training instants are important. In such case your each training instant will be of shape `[10, num of feature in each training sample(5 in this case)]`. So I guess you need little modification to create new training data, in which each instant is sequence matrix of required training samples.

The shape of your training data will be `[number of training samples(8074), seq_length(10), num_features(5)]`.

Change input shape in LSTM cell to `[sequence_length, num_features]` i.e (10,5).

This is just my limitted understanding of concept, hope this works.